# Can't compile SQLCipher on Windows

Tags: c++, c, sqlite, sqlcipher

I'm trying to compile SQLCipher. I've downloaded source code from http://sqlcipher.net/.
Then I'm doing from this post:
[http://groups.google.com/group/sqlcipher/browse_thread/thread/55c6296b56bf4533:][1]

[1]
I installed MinGW (set path to gcc: d:\MinGW\bin), OpenSSL and ActiveState Perl. I copyied file libeay32.dll to sqlcipher directory. Than I try execute this command:

```
./configure --disable-tcl CFLAGS="-DSQLITE_HAS_CODEC
-I/path/to/openssl/include" LDFLAGS="-leay32"
```

and I got error:

```
checking build system type... i686-pc-mingw32
checking host system type... i686-pc-mingw32
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name...
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See 'config.log' for more details.
```

Config.log shows:

```
configure:2537: $? = 0
configure:2544: gcc -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=D:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=d:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: mingw32
Configured with: ../gcc-4.5.2/configure --enable-languages=c,c++,ada,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --disable-sjlj-exceptions --with-dwarf2 --enable-shared --enable-libgomp --disable-win32-registry --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --disable-werror --build=mingw32 --prefix=/mingw
Thread model: win32
gcc version 4.5.2 (GCC) 
configure:2548: $? = 0
configure:2555: gcc -V >&5
gcc.exe: '-V' option must have argument
configure:2559: $? = 1
configure:2582: checking for C compiler default output file name
configure:2604: gcc -DSQLITE_HAS_CODEC -l/d/OpenSSL-Win32/bin  -libeay32 conftest.c  >&5
**d:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -ld:/OpenSSL-Win32/bin
d:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -libeay32**
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I don't know what is -leay32. I copied file libeay32.dll to sqlcipher directory. In D there is directory OpenSSL-Win32.

Thanks

Comment: Where's the C# part of this question? It looks like it's all to do with compiling C or C++ code...

Comment: My program is in C# and I want to user sqlite with encryption in it.

Comment: First error has been resolved. I got -l instead of -I

Comment: Your program may be in C#, but that's got nothing to do with the question here, which is about the C or C++ compilation part.

Comment: Yes I understand. I've remove C# tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for your configure command:

./configure –disable-tcl CFLAGS=”-DSQLITE_HAS_CODEC –Ic:/path/to/openssl/include –Lc:/path/to/openssl/lib –leay32”

-leay32 is a library flag, so think of it like "-l eay32".  It's referred to as "eay32" because the library flag ignores the "lib" of "libeay32".